# iterate through a directory of MDB and extract meta data

Tags: ms-access, vba, metadata

With the code below, we can extract table data from Access file.

Building on this, is it possible to iterate through a directory of MDBs and extract this information 1) without opening each one, or 2) opening each one but not running auto-execute macros.

```
Function dmwListAllTables() As String
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Dim tbl As AccessObject, db As Object
Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Set dB = Application.CurrentData
For Each tbl In db.AllTables
Debug.Print tbl.Name
Next tbl

strMsg = " -- Tables listing complete -- "

Procedure_Done:
dmwListAllTables = strMsg
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
strMsg = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume Procedure_Done

End Function
```

souce: http://www.consultdmw.com/access-VBA-list-objects.htm

BTW. The "loop through" part is not a problem:

```
 Sub REadThroughFiles()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("c:\myfolder\")
   While (file <> "")
      If InStr(file, "myprefix") > 0 Then
        // do something here...
      End If
     file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want any information other than table names? Should those include linked tables or only the native Access tables contained in the target MDB?

Comment: This is interesting post.  Hans, do you have answer to either?

Comment: both native Access tables and ODBC (Oracle and IBM DB2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ADO `OpenSchema` method to list the tables in an Access database.

That method requires an ADO `Connection` to the target database, which means a lock file (*.ldb* for your *.mdb* file) will be created/updated.  But if that database includes an *AutoExec* macro, the macro will not run.

```vb
Public Sub ListTables(ByVal pFullPath As String)
    Const adSchemaTables As Long = 20
    Dim cn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strProvider As String

    strProvider = CurrentProject.Connection.Provider
    strConnect = "Provider=" & strProvider & ";" & _
        "Data Source=" & pFullPath & ";"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open strConnect

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            If !TABLE_TYPE <> "VIEW" Then
                Debug.Print !TABLE_NAME
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you also want to see whether each of those items is linked table or a local table, change the `Debug.Print` line to this ...

```vb
Debug.Print !TABLE_NAME, !TABLE_TYPE
```

More information is available at [How To Use the ADO OpenSchema Method in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186246)